# Can the JVM overwrite all its memory on shutdown

Tags: java, encryption, jvm

I'm working on some application that works with secret data in memory. Is there a way to make sure all the memory is overwritten when the JVM terminates? Nothing of the secret data should be left in memory after the termination of the JVM.

Comment: What you can do is keep the secret data in arrays (`char[]` or `byte[]` for example) and clear those as soon as you donot need them anymore.  This is usually the way you should handle passwords for example, but I don't see why it couldn't work on a larger scale.

Comment: The secret data goes through a BufferedInputStream in a library function. I don't have control over this part.

Comment: How [secret](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classified_information) is your data? There are ways that could work for erasing certain parts of the memory (in the simplest form with what @john16384 said), but there's no "--secure-clear-on-exit" flag for the JVM that would do what you want. Also if you're talking about **real** secrets, don't try to roll your own solution. It's very unlikely to pass audits.

Comment: So on a scale of 1-5, with 1 being the secret knock to your treehouse club and 5 being nuke launch codes, how well do you need to protect the data?

Comment: before exiting your application you could allocate medium-sized arrays until you encounter an OOM. that should result in almost all of the heap being overwritten. But AIUI even that does not necessarily guarantee that there is no copy of the data somewhere in physical ram since the kernel might move physical pages around at some times to consolidate large pages.

Comment: @the8472: …and the optimizer could remove the allocations/clearing of unused arrays and only keep the side effect of throwing an OOME once the request is too large.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: current generation JVMs cannot guarantee that.

However, if your application is such that it requires this kind of thing, it is difficult to see how you could implement it *in any programming language* on a typical modern operating system unless you ran without a swap device.  And even then, you would probably need to rely on the OS to zero physical memory on program exit.  (Unless there are bugs, the OS *should* zero memory before giving it to another process, but I don't think it is specified when that happens.)

But this is moot.  The operating system should prevent unauthorized people / processes from seeing the memory of other processes, either during the program's execution or after it exits.  If your system has been hacked to gain "root" privilege or equivalent, you can't guarantee *either* of those.  So by the time the program exits, it is already too late!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot delete all secret data on JVM termination. In case of compacting collector (i.e all modern collectors), it may copy data from one location to another. Hence when you overwrite your array, the data would still exist in the old location, but you won;t have any reference to it so you cannot overwrite it.

The best you can do is to overwrite the current location (if you store the data in arrays) and hold it in memory for as little time as possible, to minimize the chance (but you cannot avoid it on 100%) that secret data will remain in the heap during compaction.

Comment: You could still overwrite the data with raw memory access, but the problematic issue here seems to be with the library accessing the secret data.